# Finding a point on a given line that passes through the midpoint of another line segment

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

The exercise is written as,

> Find a point P upon the line r: -3x + 4y + 1 = 0, such as that the line which contains the segment OP (O: origin of coordinates) passes through the midpoint of the line segment AB, where A = (2,1) and B = (1,1).

I know how to find the cartesian equation of a line given two points, but I'm not sure if I need to do that for the exercise. I also know that the midpoint is the sum of the x and y coordinates of each point over two.

I also know that if the lines are perpendicular to each other, then the dot product is zero.

However I'm really unsure of how to find a point upon that line, or even if I'm looking in the right direction at the exercise.

Comment: The midpoint of $AB$ is $(A+B)/2=(3/2,1)$. The line that passes through the origin and that point is parametrized by $t\mapsto (A+B)t/2=(3t/2,t)$. The point on the line and $r$ satisfies $-3(3t/2)+4t+1=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how to compute the intersection of two lines ?  If so, let $C$ be the mid of segment $[AB]$, i.e. $C=\frac{A+B}{2}$ and let $\rho$ be the line going through O and C (whose equation should not be too hard).  Those two lines are the line described in the problem.  Since lines intersect at one point at most and $P$ belongs to both, you can compute $P$ by computing the intersection between line $r$ and line $\rho$.